# Maven - POM resolves dependencies in Eclipse but not when deploying

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm pretty new to troubleshooting Maven problems and need some direction. My project is in eclipse and I'm using the m2eclipse plugin. When i import my project to eclipse all dependencies are resolved and its business as usual. However when i deploy to one of my shared environments the mvn deploy is failing due to "package ... does not exist" exception on some Spring components. I'm also seeing alot of "cannot find symbol" issues.

The first thing i checked was the Settings.xml file I used locally against what the shared environment is using and they are the same.

Any suggestions on what else could be causing the deploy to fail? BTW my POM uses teh repositories tag to specify an additional repository however this doesnt seem to be having any affect on the failing deploy.

Thanks,

```
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
```

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind: profiles for dependency management. Simple check your project settings in eclipse (right click project - properties - maven - active profiles). If one exist, you might miss the profile when executing mvn deploy (add -Pprofile).

Comment: It actually seems that dependencies are being resolved, but javac fails with mentioned exceptions - which can be caused by getting different artifact versions from 'pure' maven than you get in eclipse

Comment: would this require a purge of the repository on the shared environment?

Comment: I would try purging the local repository on the development machine running Eclipse, then `mvn package` from a command prompt, not from Eclipse. Let `javac` complain about the missing classes, then use grepcode or jarvana to figure out which libraries include those classes, and add those jars to the dependencies for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your dependencies are using the wrong scope, which causes the libraries not be be included in e.g. the output war file.

As a first step I would confirm that your build passes on the command line and maybe share your pom file here.

Comment: the issue was related to conflicting dependencies. I used the maven enforcer plugin (http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to identify the conflicts and resolved the issue. I'll mark your answer as correct as it lead to the solution